# Dynamic Form Elements state with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript

Can someone please help me figure this one out.  I have a form element that is dependent on certain values from another select.  It is only visible if certain values are selected.  I know i can do multiple conditions using different form elements.  However, how can i specify the same form element having multiple values.  Right now this only works for the last value.

```
$form['listing_attributes']['sort_by'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t("Sort By"),
'#description' => t('How you would like the listing to be sorted by.'),
'#options' => array(
    'alphabetical' => t('Alphabetical'),
    'program_type' => t('Program Type'),                
    'level' => t('Degree Level'),       
    'subject' => t('Subject'),      
    'category' => t('Category'),
),
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="listing_page"]' => array('value' => 'school_page'),
    ),
),
);  

$form['listing_attributes']['group_by'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t("Group By"),
'#description' => t('How you would like the sorted list to be grouped by.'),
'#options' => array(
    'program_type' => t('Program Type'),                
    'level' => t('Degree Level'),       
    'subject' => t('Subject'),      
    'category' => t('Category'),
),
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="sort_by"]' => array('value' => 'level'),
    ':input[name="sort_by"]' => array('value' => 'category'),
    ':input[name="sort_by"]' => array('value' => 'subject'),        
    ),
),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to use the "!" in order to specify what element i do not want it to show up for.  Its certainly an option and i can definitely use it.  Just thought you

```
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="sort_by"]' => array('!value' => 'alphabetical'),  
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

ORs are [not supported](http://drupal.org/node/735528) at the moment, I think its something in the pipeline but may not be included in Drupal 7.

However there is [a workaround](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7#comment-24708) available, it's a bit hacky but will get you the desired effect.

Comment: i dont have privileges to answer my own question yet.  I have to wait a bit to do so but thanks for your suggestion and i will do exactly that once i get the privilege to do so.